# Change fontcolor onclick

Tags: css, fonts, onclick

I try to change my fontcolor onclick but it doesn't work :D

My js function:

```
    function changeColor(id, col) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.color = col;
        return false;
    }
```

The first div is a img-file. I want to press on the image and change the color of the 2nd div "txt_raum_ein"

```
    <div id="but_bel_raum_ein" onclick="changeColor("txt_raum_ein", "green")"></div>
    <div id="txt_raum_ein"><font size = "+2" face="Arial">RAUM EIN</font></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this when you click on image word the below name color will be change

```js
 function changeColor(id, col) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.color = col;
        return false;
    }
```

```html
<div id="but_bel_raum_ein" onclick="changeColor('txt_raum_ein', 'green')">image</div>
   <div id="txt_raum_ein"><font size = "+2" face="Arial">RAUM EIN</font></div>
```

Comment: and i want to give it a parameter... don't know why, buut this: changeColor("txt_raum_ein") doesn't work

Comment: Yes @MarcelKoch because the changes store only in the browser when you refresh the webpage the original data will be shown. Check I update the code as per your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in parameters using single quotes, rather than double quotes. For example:

```js
  function changeColor(id, col) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.color = col;
        return false;
    }
```

```html
<div id="but_bel_raum_ein" onclick="changeColor('txt_raum_ein', 'green')">image</div>
   <div id="txt_raum_ein"><font size = "+2" face="Arial">RAUM EIN</font></div>
```

Comment: if i do this, my website is not displayed any more :P

Comment: @MarcelKoch Can you explain by what you mean by this? Is there an error?

Comment: i just see an empty page instead of my normal website when i use single quotes...don't know why.